# Large floating point exponent with modulo in python

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, exponential

i want to calculate (e**a)%m where a is floating point number (<=174003.27216422465) and m is integer (<=10^9). since the exponent is large it cant be done using pow and also creating square root power function is not possible as i cant check a%2. is there any way in python to calculate as there is in mysql.

> for eg:
>
> a=5.30102999566398 and m= 24 answer is 8.

Comment: This is a rather unnatural thing to want to do.  Where's this coming from?  Are you *sure* that `a` is a non-integer here?

Comment: In your example, what's `e`?

Comment: e is 2.718281828459045...

Comment: what i m trying to do is taking natural log of a series and then after some computation want to take its antilog and i cant ignore its decimal part as it will decrease its precision.